# Passing basic auth username to a shell script

Tags: http, shell, basic-authentication

I have a weird requirement. I have a webserver setup with http basic auth. Is there a way to pass the username and/or the password a user enters to a shell script with in the environment?

I know apache has this information because I can see it in the `access_log` and `error_log` files. I am mainly just interested in the username so I can store that in a txt files upon an authenticated login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP, this info is available in the $_SERVER superglobal, so you can just do:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/log/file', $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```